# pyodbc 3.0.10 fails to install OS X 10.10

Tags: python, macos, compilation, pyodbc

I'm trying to install the latest version of pyodbc on os x yosemite.

I can get 3.0.7 to install (but on python3 this reports as 3.0.0 unsupported)

I am getting the following errors when running:

`sudo python3 setup.py build install`

`ld: library not found for -lodbc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit status 1`

I have got an ODBC driver install and can use this with python2 and python2 reports 3.0.7 is the version used (same download!)

It looks like something has changed on the compilation (previously I've had to copy all the .h files to my /usr/include from the Iodbc download.

I'm now a bit stuck

Any help please ? I'm not getting any answers on the github project.

Comment: What version of Python 3 are you running? I've been running pyodbc 3.0.7 on Python 3.3 and 3.4 for a while now.

Comment: I'm on 3.4.3 and I can install 3.0.7 but it only reports in as 3.0.0==unsupported.

Comment: I managed to get 3.0.10 installed today but using homebrew to install 'unixodbc', however, when I run my python code its now broken due to the unixODBC , I've had to drop back to 3.0.0==unsupported. Any clues on the unixODBC driver bit , I had all my connections working via http://www.odbcmanager.net/

Comment: `pip freeze` is reporting 3.0.0?

Comment: pip3 freeze reports pyodbc===3.0.0-unsupported

Comment: If the answer I gave below doesn't work for you, can you do a `pip3 --version` and let me know the version you're running so I can try to repro the issue? I'm on version 7.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may need to do a `pip install` of the ZIP file directly. This works for me:

```
pip install https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip
```

That should install 3.0.7 directly. Here's an example, using a virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper:

```
[vagrant@vagrant test]$ mkvirtualenv myvenv
(myvenv)[vagrant@vagrant test]$ pip install https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip

Collecting https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip
  Using cached https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc
Successfully installed pyodbc-3.0.7
(myvenv)[vagrant@vagrant test]$ pip freeze
pyodbc==3.0.7
```

Since that works, you could try to install the newer 3.0.10 (replace pip with pip3 in your case; most people will be using pip):

```
pip uninstall pyodbc
pip install pyodbc==3.0.10
```

Give that a try. If it doesn't work, I'd stick with 3.0.7 for now. There is no install ZIP for 3.0.10 (yet), as the pyodbc project is being moved to GitHub from Google Code (which is closing).

Comment: Cool that worked for 3.0.7! `pip3 install https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip`

Comment: Great! I'm glad we got it figured out.

Comment: would it be pushing it to try getting 3.0.10 working ;-)